# Java Runtime constant pool reference variable in stack frame

Tags: java, jvm

According to the following link the java stack frame contains local variables, operand stack and the current class constant pool reference.
http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html

Also From Oracle "Structure of JVM" Section 2.6.3. "Dynamic Linking - Each frame (§2.6) contains a reference to the run-time constant pool (§2.5.5) for the type of the current method to support dynamic linking of the method code."

I have also read that the object in the heap also has a pointer/reference to the class data.
https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm6.html

The stack frame will contain the "current class constant pool reference" and also it will have the reference to the object in heap which in turn will also point to the class data. Is this not redundant??

For example.

```
public class Honda {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("honda is running");
  } 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Honda h = new Honda();
  h.run(); //output honda is running
  }
}
```

When h.run() is going to be executed, jvm will create a new stack frame and push h on the stack frame. h will point to the object in heap which in turn will have a pointer to class data of Honda. The stack frame will also have current class constant reference. Is this correct? If not please shed some light on this.

Comment: Static methods don't have a `this` reference on the stack.

Comment: ... and two of your three citations are non-normative, by which I mean arbitrary Internet rubbish of no status or standing.

Comment: To prove the non-normative point of @EJP, the [first link](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html) has a section "[Operand Stack](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html#operand_stack)" which says that `int i;` would generate 2 byte code instructions: `iconst_0` and `istore_1`. That is certainly not the case, since local variables don't have a default value. Statement `int i = 0;` would generate that byte code, but not the code in the article. The article is *flawed*.

Comment: In fact a local declaration without an initializer doesn't generate any bytecode at all. @Andreas.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this not redundant??

Maybe it is redundant for instance methods and constructors.

It isn't redundant for static methods or class initialization pseudo-methods.

---

It is also possible that the (supposedly) redundant reference gets optimized away by the JIT compiler.  (Or maybe it isn't optimized away ... because they have concluded that the redundancy leads to faster execution *on average*.)  Or maybe the actual implementation of the JVM<sup>1</sup> is just different.

Bear in mind that the JVM spec is describing an idealized stack frame.  The actual implementation may be different ... provided that it *behaves* the way that the spec says it should.

---

On @EJP's point on normativeness, the only normative references for Java are the JLS and JVM specifications, and the Javadoc for the class library. You can also consult the source code of the JVM itself.  The specifications say what *should* happen, and the code (in a sense) says what *does* happen.  An article you might find in a published paper or a web article is not normative, and may well be incorrect or out of date.

---

<sup>1 - The actual implementation may vary from one version to the next, or between vendors.  Furthermore, I have heard of a JVM implementation where a bytecode rewriter transformed from standard bytecodes to another abstract machine language at class load time.  It wasn't a great idea from a performance perspective ... but it was certainly within the spirit of the JVM spec.</sup>

Comment: Thank You. Yes I do try to follow JLS however on many occassions I am not able to follow it and have to search for other sources which dumb it down for me.

Comment: @cloud In that case you should stick to official sources like the Oracle Java Tutorial and other Oracle or IBM Java documentation. There is a dreadful amount of rubbish out there. The two sources I mentioned aren't too bad, considering, but you really can't rely on third-party stuff.

Comment: @EJP Thank You for the sources. Will try to refer to these from now on.

Comment: A follow up question. What happens when the reference variable is of parent class and it is pointing to object of a child class? The constant pool reference in the stack frame will point to constant pool of the parent class or the child class?

Comment: The constant pool reference needs to point to the pool that corresponds to the class that declared the method being executed.  Whichever class that is.

Comment: @Stephen C If the method is overridden then it will be declared and defined in both parent and child class. Now the reference variable is of parent class and it is pointing to the object to child class. In this case the constant pool reference will point to which class? I am assuming the child class since that method gets executed.

Comment: A (non-abstract) method is declared in *exactly* one place.  In subclasses, the parent class method is inherited, not declared ... unless it is overridden.  (This is standard Java terminology ...) Reread my previous comment in the light of this.  If the parent method is not overridden in the child, then you are executing the method declared in the parent and the reference points to the parent class constant pool.   (But this is common sense.  The constant pool for the child class won't contain the parent classes constants ... will it.)

Answer (score 1):

> The stack frame will contain the "current class constant pool reference" and also it will have the reference to the object in heap which in turn will also point to the class data. Is this not redundant??

You missed the precondition of that statement, or you misquoted it, or it was just plainly wrong where you saw it.

The "reference to the object in heap" is only added for non-static method, and it refers to the hidden `this` parameter.

As it says in section "[Local Variables Array](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html#local_variables_array)":

> The array of local variables contains all the variables used during the execution of the method, including a reference to `this`, all method parameters and other locally defined variables. For class methods (i.e. static methods) the method parameters start from zero, however, **for instance method the zero slot is reserved for `this`**.

So, for static methods, there is no redundancy.

Could the constant pool reference be eliminated when `this` is present? Yes, but then there would need to be a different way to locate the constant pool reference, requiring different bytecode instructions, so that would be a different kind of redundancy.

Always having the constant pool reference available in a well-known location in the stack frame, simplifies the bytecode logic.

Comment: Yes my question was for when "this" is present. Apologies if I couldn't frame it better. So I gather what you are saying is that for instance method when "this" is present and if there is no constant pool reference on stack frame then using "this" jvm can locate the object on heap and this will lead to the class data but not directly to the constant pool and jvm will have to again locate the constant pool inside of the class data. So its better to have a direct reference to the constant pool?

Comment: @cloud (a) It is consistent with static methods, and (b) it is more efficient than omitting it (because (i) it saves a runtime test as to whether it is a static method, and (ii) it saves an indirection).

Comment: Thank you @EJP, that's a great summary of what I was trying to say.

Comment: got it. Thank You Andreas and EJP.

Comment: @EJP Well, actually, even the presence of a `this` does not imply a way to get the constant pool (in a trivial way), as the actual type of `this` is not necessarily the class containing the code, whose constant pool we actually need. Searching the class hierarchy or even the interfaces would not only be inefficient, it would require recording the code’s actual declaring class somewhere, to be able to compare, and if we need to store something of that kind, different to the `this` instance, why not store a reference to the declaring class’ constant pool in the first place…

Answer (score 0):

There are two points here. First, there are `static` methods which are invoked without a `this` reference. Second, the actual class of an object instance is not necessarily the declaring class of the method whose code we are actually executing. The purpose of the constant pool reference is to enable resolving of symbolic references and loading of constants referenced by the code. In both cases, we need the constant pool of the class containing the currently executed code, even if the method might be inherited by the actual class of the `this` reference (in case of a `private` method invoked by another inherited method, we have a method invoked with a `this` instance of a class which formally does not even inherit the method).

It might even be the case that the currently executed code is contained in an interface, so we never have instances of it, but still a class file with a constant pool which must be available when executing the code. This does not only apply to Java 8 and newer, which allow `static` and `default` methods in interfaces; earlier versions also might need to execute the `<clinit>` method of an interface to initialize its `static` fields.

By the way, even if an instance method is invoked with an object reference associated with `this` in its first local variable, there is no requirement for the bytecode instructions to keep it there. If not needed, it might get overwritten by an arbitrary value, reusing the variable slot for other purposes. This does not preclude that subsequent instructions need the constant pool, which, as said, does not need to belong to the actual class of `this` anyway.

Of course, that pool reference is a logical construct anyway. Implementations may transform the code to use a shared pool or not to need a pool at all when all references have been resolved already, etc. After inlining, code may not even have a dedicated stack frame anymore.